# endpoint to call to DELETE config-vars using heroku API

Tags: javascript, node.js, crud, http-delete, heroku-api

working on a project and using heroku API for my project,
Can't seem to find the endpoint/url to fetch a single app or to delete config-vars.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, just set key and value to null..
‍♀️